# Ruby Complexity / Time explaination

Tags: ruby, data-structures, time-complexity

I am using HackerRank to improve my ruby skills. I am on the Data Structures - Array Manipulation problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem

My solution is listed first, a supposedly "correct" solution I haven't been able to implement is listed last. My solution works for all test cases except **VERY ** large numbers, it fails due to timeout. I know this is because of a loop, but can someone offer a different solution, and explain why theirs works?

EXPLAINATION OF PROBLEM:

Sample Input

```
5 3
1 2 100
2 5 100
3 4 100
#n=5 m=3, then following numbers leftIndex=1 rightIndex=3 sum=100 and so on
```

Sample Output

```
200
```

Explanation

```
After the first update list will be 100 100 0 0 0. 
After the second update list will be 100 200 100 100 100. 
After the third update list will be 100 200 200 200 100. 
The required answer will be 200.
```

OR

Explain how the why the bottom solution can work without looping?

```
#Problem Data Set, my solution times out for the listed data set

10000000 100000
[
 [1400906,9889280,90378],
 [6581237,9872072,87106],
 [4386373,9779851,52422],
 [198648,4373818,5289]
]
# For this problem, variables will look like:
n = 10000000
m = 100000
q = [[1400906,9889280,90378],[6581237,9872072,87106],[4386373,9779851,52422],[198648,4373818,5289]]


def arrayManipulation(n, q)
  arr = Array.new(n,0)
  max = 0
  q.size.times do |i|
    left, right, value = q[i][0],q[i][1],q[i][2]
    left -= 1
    (left...right).each do |j|
      arr[j] += value
      max = arr[j] if max < arr[j]
    end
  end
  return max
end
# this times out on HackerRank, please explain better solution, 
#or why the bottom solution works!

result = arrayManipulation n, queries
```

Working SOlution on Discussion board

```
N, M = gets.chomp.split(' ').map(&:to_i)

# create array of zeros of length N + 1
arr = Array.new(N + 1, 0)

M.times do
  # cycle through and get the inputs
  start, finish, value = gets.chomp.split(' ').map(&:to_i)

  # increment value at start of sequence
  arr[start - 1] += value

  # decrement value at first position after sequence
  arr[finish] -= value
end

tmp = 0
max = 0

arr.each do |value|
  # step through summing array
  tmp += value

  # capture the max value of tmp
  max = tmp if max < tmp
end

puts max
```

Comment: Please post the problem itself into the question. Questions should be as independent as possible; additional data or different presentation is welcome on links, but the question should be understandable without them.

Comment: See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55569655/1601309) for run time analysis of this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55569655/1601309

Answer (score 4):

Your code is `O(m * n)` as you have a nested loop to update the array for each entry.

The working code is `O(m + n)`: it never really stores the array, it stores the delta array, the array of changes that makes it possible to reconstruct the array. In your first example, it would store:

```
0    0    0    0    0   0
+100 0    -100 0    0   0
+100 +100 -100 0    0   -100
+100 +100 0    0   -100 -100
```

This requires only a loop of `m` iterations, no nested loops; then you need another loop of `n` iterations to run through the array, keep running total, and identify the maximum of it.